# IE 7 stops responding

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

In our asp.net 2.0 web application, there is a user control with validation. For some reason, when the validation fails, the pages looks fine, however, no controls (asp buttons, scroll bars, or third party like Telerik text editor) respond to mouse inputs. The only work around is to resize the browser window which will make the UI responsive.
Has anyone seen this issue before? What could be causing it?

Comment: We only support IE. So other browsers are not tested. It appears to be an issue on the client side. One thing to mention is that it is happening inside a asp.net Wizard. I used IE dev toolbar to explore the page, but there were NO transparent elements that it would pick up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your CSS and/or javascript. It sounds like there is a transparent element (like a div) beging placed over the elements in the page.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen in other browsers?
Are you talking client side validation or server side (does it actually post back?)
Have you tried removing all CSS and seeing if it still happens? If it doesn't, add the css back bit by bit until it break again and youve found the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen IE freeze up when resizing if there are expressions in the CSS.

```
#container{
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth > 1100)? "1100px" : "auto";
}
```

It's easy to get yourself into a situation where two elements are resizing based on each other, which can cause an infinite loop where the browser locks. In any case, expressions will [stop working](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx) in IE8 standards mode, so they should be removed anyway.